# How can I print only lines with a certain float value in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I do not have much experience with Python but I am working on a code where I need to manipulate data and delete/remove several hundred lines.  I have my data in a pandas dataframe and there is one column where much of the data starts with the number 4.61 with random digits after the 1. I am trying to print only the lines that DO NOT have 4.61 at the beginning of this column. This is what I have so far,

```py
remove_foursixone = df.loc[df[' Conductance (G0) '] != str.startswith('4.61')]

print(remove_foursixone)
```

but it won't work because `str.startswith` needs a string type but I am working with floats. I tried converting the data in the Conductance column to a string type using

```py
df[' Conductance (G0) '] = df[' Conductance (G0) '].astype(str)
```

but this returns `dtype('O')` and still does not allow me to use the `str.startswith()` function.  Any suggestions for the best way to approach this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try:

```
remove_foursixone = df.loc[~df['Conductance (G0)'].astype(str).str.startswith('4.61')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df[(df[col_name] < 4.61) | (df[col_name] >= 4.62)]
```

This way you exclude all values in range `[4.61; 4.62[`.